# TypeScript can't implement interface

Tags: typescript

Given the following interface

```
interface Expando {
    new<T extends {}>(template: T): T & Expando;
}
```

I tried to implement this like so

```
class Expando implements ExpandoConstructor {
    constructor(template: {}) {

    }
}
```

But I get an error because the constructor definition is incomplete. How do I implement this interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a class implement a constructor interface because this interface describes static properties of the class.

You can do this:

```
interface ExpandoConstructor {
    new<T extends {}>(template: T): T & Expando;
}

class Expando {
    constructor(template: {}) {}
}

let ctor = Expando as ExpandoConstructor;
let instance = new ctor({});
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ExpandoConstructor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%3CT%20extends%20%7B%7D%3E(template%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20Expando%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Expando%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(template%3A%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20ctor%20%3D%20Expando%20as%20ExpandoConstructor%3B%0Alet%20instance%20%3D%20new%20ctor(%7B%7D)%3B))